# Presto: Create new columns with some default values

Tags: string, presto, cross-join

My data does not have columns of label and source, I want to add new columns for label and source in the data. However, the values are fixed and it doesn't matter which row gets which value.

I want to add column label = ('A', 'B', 'C')
and source = ('X', 'Y', 'Z')

The data already has over 500 rows, I just want new columns to arbitrarily take any of these 3 values. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you want to read your data, projecting additional `label` and `source` columns, randomly.

You can do this by adding a projection using [`random`](https://prestosql.github.io/docs.prestosql.io/current/functions/math.html#random) like

- `ARRAY['A', 'B', 'C'][1 + random(3)] AS label`
- same for `source`

Example:

```
presto:default> SELECT *, ARRAY['A', 'B', 'C'][1 + random(3)] AS label
             -> FROM (VALUES 1,2,3,4) t(data);
 data | label
------+-------
    1 | C
    2 | A
    3 | B
    4 | B
(4 rows)
```

(tested on Presto 322)